# Why cannot use 2 separate foreign keys for same model in django model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, chat

I have a theoretical model that isn't working:

```
class Message(models.Model):
       text = models.TextField()
       created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
       receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now if a user messaged someone, like a private message thread, you have someone who sent it, and someone who received it, which is important to know. Both of these should be a one-to-many I think because each user can send infinite messages. Senders and receivers are users, from the same model User, but they must be different people. I get django whining about

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
chat.Message.receiver: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Message.receiver' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Message.sender'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Message.receiver' or 'Message.sender'.
chat.Message.sender: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Message.sender' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Message.receiver'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Message.sender' or 'Message.receiver'.
```

Should I add `unique=True` since you can't send messages to yourself? Is this a bad way to implement messages between users? And what is my error? Thank you,

Cody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says add the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument to the foreign key definitions:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text        = models.TextField()
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sender      = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_sent')
    receiver    = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_received')
```

These related names can be used in the [backward relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='johndoe')
messages_from = user.messages_sent.all()
messages_to = user.messages_received.all()
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='johndoe')
messages_from = Messages.objects.filter(sender=user)
messages_to = Messages.objects.filter(receiver=user)
```

Comment: and where do I later use this related name sir? I'm saving the 'receiver' as 'username' in 
`url(r'^message/(?P<username>\w+)/$',  views.message`,
and I am holding the sender in the usual request.user field

Comment: This related name is used while following relation backward: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects  If you don't want to create backwrd relation then you can set the `related_name` to `'+'`. I updated the answer with the link to the `related_name` documentation.