# Django- Error when creating intermediate many to many model

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-migration

I'm currently writing a Django App were one of the features involves users being able to send invite to other users where each invite will be stored in invites database table. In order to do this, I followed the structure provided in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/) as well as this [blog post](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/). Here are the models for Users and the invites (the intermediate model):

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
    invites = models.ManyToManyField('self', through = 'Invite', 
        symmetrical = False )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Invite(models.Model):
    sender_id = models.Foreignkey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    recipient_id = models.Foreignkey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    concert_id = models.AutoField()
    artist_id = models.AutoField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
```

For some reason, when I try to run the DB migrations, I get an attribute error saying that the module object has no attribute Foreignkey, in reference to the line where the `sender_id` is defined. Based on the code provided in docs, the models object does have the attribute Foreignkey, so what could be the problem?

Comment: unrelated to the question, but django already has a standard user model. if you're gonna use authentication at all or something like that you should consider extending it for your personal needs instead of creating a whole new one, or even creating a new model with all the extra info ( not in the standard user model) and a OneToOneField pointing to the user model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ForeignKey` is written with a capital K, as in:

```
sender_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

That should fix this problem, but you probably will also have to add a related_name attribute to one or both of the foreign keys, since they're both pointing to the same model ([Why cannot use 2 separate foreign keys for same model in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785949/why-cannot-use-2-separate-foreign-keys-for-same-model-in-django-model))

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error with the Foreign Key not being recognized. I followed instructions from the link that you included for using a related name for each of the instances of the user models and now a name error has been raised.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 if you haven't solved it yet, just start a new question and I'll find it :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124921/django-how-to-map-messages-sent-between-users#) is the question for the issue I'm dealing with now:

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 left my answer there :)